# Pairs (Cluster) Bootstrap R

Tags: r, bootstrap, standard-error, cluster-sample

When using a regressor ("generated regressor") that is generated in a first-stage equation and used in a second-stage equation, then standard errors will be understated (here is a readable introduction, https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1475-679X.12470).

This is because the standard error bias associated with a generated regressor derives from the sampling error inherent in the first-step regression coefficient estimates, used in creating the generated regressor.

In the minimal working example below, you may think of "y_hat_fs", the predicted values of the first stage as some type of competition metric, that is generated and used in the second stage regression as a regressor (In general, the two datasets are not identical and may have a different number of observations, ids can be thought to be "stores" or "gas stations".

In the second-stage regression, the standard error of the variable labelled "generated variable" is biased.

A solution to this problem is the "pairs cluster bootstrap", which includes the first and the second stage regression.

This involved multiple steps (see source above, also for a pair cluster bootstrap):

1. Randomly draw with replacement a bootstrap sample of size N from the sample used in the first-step regression, where N is the number of observations in the full sample of the first-step regression
2. Estimate the first-step regression using the bootstrap sample
3. Use the first-step regression output to generate the regressor of interest, that is, the generated regressor
4. Estimate the second-step regression using the bootstrap sample and the generated regressor, and store the coefficient estimates
5. Repeat this process a large number of times
6. Use the standard deviations of the collected coefficient estimates as the bootstrapped standard errors.

There are many packages that allow bootstrapping the second stage, however, none of the packages (to my knowledge) allow for "the pairs bootstrap".

I'm especially unsure how to derive the correct standard errors from a bunch of collected coefficient estimates, see step 6.

Here is a minimal simplified working example (regressions are run using the fixest package for efficiency reasons, the regressions run on the bootstrap sample have 17 million observations, the second stage consists of 160,000 observations). Any help (or hint to resources) on how to conduct a "pair bootstrap" in R is highly appreciated.

```
library("tidyverse")
library("fixest")

set.seed(123456789)


 # First Stage~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 # Data first Stage ---------
 data_fs  <- tibble(x1 = rnorm(100), 
               x2 = rnorm(100),  
               y  = rnorm(100), 
               cluster = rep(letters[1:4],25), 
               time = rep(2020:2024,20),
               id = rep(c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"), 20))


 # First Stage Regression, which produces generated regressor. 
 fsreg <- feols(y~ x1+x2| id + time, cluster = ~cluster, data = data_fs)
 # Get Table
 etable(fsreg)
  
 # Get predicted values
 y_hat_fs <- fsreg$fitted.values

 # Second Stage ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 # Data Second Stage 
data_ss <- tibble(z  = rnorm(100), 
                  x1 = rnorm(100), 
                  x2 = rnorm(100), 
                  cluster =(rep(letters[1:4], 25)),
                  time = rep(2020:2024, 20), 
                  id = rep(c("id1", 
                         "id2", 
                         "id3", 
                         "id4"),25), 
              y_hat_fs = y_hat_fs)

  # Second Stage Regression ~~~~~~~~~~~
  ss_reg <- feols(z ~ x1 + x2 +y_hat_fs| id+ time, cluster = ~cluster, data =  data_ss)
  #Get Table 
  etable(ss_reg, dict = c(y_hat_fs= "Generated Variable"))
```

Comment: "5. Repeat this process a large number of times" - is this process repeating step 4 or repeating steps 1-4?

Comment: Hello Henry, steps 1 to 4 have to be repeated many times, usually anything between 200-1000 times ( preferably 1000 times, if computationally feasible)